# Modelo relacional banco de dados com SKU

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional

Estou criando um sistema para venda de produtos e necessito que esses produtos possam tem preços diferentes de acordo com seu tamanho ou cor, para isso estou utilizando SKU, estou criando o modelo relacional deste banco de dados e gostaria de saber se este modelo que criei está adequado e irá me permitir que eu busque os produtos de acordo com o SKU e ele me traga todas as informações como o nome do produto, preço, etc.

Por exemplo:

Se tenho uma bota tamanho P e G, e na Cor Rosa e Preta, eu teria que ser capaz de buscar uma Bota Preta do tamanho P, ou uma G da cor Rosa, utilizando para isso o SKU, com esse modelo que criei isso seria possível?

Segue o modelo:
[image: DER]

Caso alguém queira [importar o modelo no seu MySQL Workbench](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57264398/sku_db.mwb).

Comment: O que quer dizer SKU? E qual é exatamente sua dúvida Marcos?

Comment: Esse artigo explica oque é SKU: http://sitesmais.com/2011/12/o-que-e-o-sku-de-um-produto/

Comment: Se tenho uma bota tamanho P e G, e na Cor Rosa e Preta, eu teria que ser capaz de buscar uma Bota Preta do tamanho P, ou uma G da cor Rosa, utilizando para isso o SKU, com esse modelo que criei isso seria possível?

Answer (score 1):

Parece adequado, mas pode não ser. Você é a pessoa que mais conhece o problema real e tem dúvidas, imagine nós que não temos ideia onde isso será usado, de que forma, quais as necessidades de hoje e de amanhã.

O que eu quero dizer é que tanta coisa pode dar errada ou mudar, então pessoas aleatórias na internet tem menos condições de dizer se tudo dará certo do que você próprio. Tem que fazer o melhor possível e estar preparado para possíveis mudanças, não fazer nada que dificulte mudar depois. Isso é muito raro de se ver, aí reside o real problema.

Na verdade tenho muinhas dúvidas se precisa tudo isso. Me parece que na verdade algumas dessas tabelas tem relação 1:1 e nesse caso não vejo muita vantagem estar em tabela separada. Pra mim as tabelas ligadas ao SKU deveriam ser colunas simples na própria tabela, mesmo após o comentário abaixo não vejo motivo para essas tabelas existirem. Provavelmente eu simplificaria eliminando 5 tabelas. Mas quem sou eu pra dizer o que deve fazer, ainda pode ser que tenha algo que eu não sei, por isso fica difícil responder.

Eu tenho até dúvidas se deveria ter uma separação entre produto e SKU. Até vejo alguma utilidade, mas pode não ser necessário. Muitos sistemas possuem o que seria só o SKU, afinal se cada SKU é diferente, é outro produto e o que chama de produto talvez seja um grupo.

Acho estranho `produto_tamanho` ter relação com o produto e com SKU, isso parece um erro.

Nem vou falar dos nomes confusos, aí é gosto. Nem tudo deve ser `VARCHAR(45)`, isso é um problema que vai além da modelagem, ou seja, esse é um problema tão grande que fazendo assim qualquer modelagem "servirá". Esse tipo de coisa dificultará mudanças futuras. Mas eu imagino que o que mais dificultará nem dá para ver neste modelo.

Se a pergunta tivesse colocada como texto e não como imagem eu teria reformulado o modelo e postado aqui como eu faria.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md)

Comment: Obg pelo feedback, é o seguinte, é uma loja de produtos ortopédicos então podem haver muitas variáveis por isso essa complexidade toda, por exemplo, um produto pode ter um preço para uma cor e outro preço para uma cor diferente, um preço para um tamanho e outro preço para um tamanho diferente por isso tantas tabelas intende?  Sobre os VARCHAR e outros tipos isso eu ainda irei mudar, ai está algo inicial por isso alguma incorreções, e sobre os nomes eu ainda não acertei todos também.

Comment: Minha resposta permanece a mesma.

Answer (score 1):

O modelo que você fez deve atender as necessidades atuais do seu projeto, não deve se preocupar tanto com o que poderá ocorrer no futuro, o mais importante é que ele atenda às necessidades de agora e que esteja com uma estrutura bem relacionada. Quanto mais abstrato, e mais simples, melhor. Porém, isso não deve ser confundido com falta de parâmetros ou tabelas. Uma maneira que você pode fazer para conseguir montar um banco de dados de uma forma bacana: pense como se fosse montar uma empresa com escritórios, departamentos, onde você deverá criar cada setor, e cada um com sua devida responsabilidade, agora pense em como eles deverão se comunicar entre si. Partindo dessa abstração, é mais fácil entender como irá funcionar as entidades e seus relacionamentos. O que vir no futuro, você implementa depois.

**Obs:** Só lembrando que o que você está fazendo, é basicamente reescrever a roda, já que existem modelos prontos de cms que possuem estruturas bem elaboradas para banco de dados de produtos. Como as lojas virtuais: [OsCommerce](https://www.oscommerce.com), [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/), [Prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com/pt), [Magento](https://magento.com/) etc.

Inclusive, existe [**outros modelos**](http://files.e2t-ti.webnode.com.br/200000038-86a0e879b0/Mer%20Conceitual%20v5.png) que você pode se basear, para estudar o seu que já estão prontos. Basta fazer uma pequena pesquisa pela Internet por MER, DER, ER. [**Aqui tem**](http://e2t-ti.webnode.com.br/products/bcon-business-control/) outros exemplos.